# jQuery plugin + AMD = how to access functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, js-amd

I am wrapping up my jQuery plugin in an AMD environment. This is my boilerplate,

```
!function(root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else {
        factory(root.jQuery);
    }
}(this, function($) {

    var defaults = {
       target: ''
    };

    var myPlugin = function(options) {
        options = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);

        return options;
    };

    myPlugin.prototype = {
        init: function(options) {
            return options;
        }
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = myPlugin;

});

console.log($.fn.myPlugin.init());
```

error,

> TypeError: $.fn.myPlugin.init is not a function
>
> console.log($.fn.myPlugin.init());

Any ideas what I have done incorrectly? And how can I access the function inside `myPlugin.prototype = {...}`?

**EDIT:**

tested with this [boilerplate](https://gist.github.com/simonsmith/4353587),

```
console.log($('.test li').plugin({
        test: 'option1',
        test2: 'option2'
    }));
```

result,

```
Object[] // why is it empty?
```

And

```
console.log($.fn.plugin.someMethod());
```

result,

> TypeError: $.fn.plugin.someMethod is not a function
>
> console.log($.fn.plugin.someMethod());

And,

```
// Plugin methods and shared properties
    Plugin.prototype = {
        // Reset constructor - http://goo.gl/EcWdiy
        constructor: Plugin,

        someMethod: function(options) {
            return options;
        }
    };

console.log($.fn.plugin.Plugin.prototype.someMethod("hello world"));
```

result,

```
hello world
```

And,

```
var instance = $('.element').data('plugin');
    instance.someMethod("hello world");
```

result,

> TypeError: instance is null // what does it mean? It should return 'hello world', isn't it?
>
> instance.someMethod("hello world");

**EDIT 2:**

```
var plugin = $('.element').plugin();
    var instance = $('.element').data('plugin',plugin);
    console.log(instance); // returns - Object[]
    console.log(instance.someMethod("hello world"));
```

result,

> TypeError: instance.someMethod is not a function
>
> console.log(instance.someMethod("hello world"));

Comment: ex: $(body).myPlugin.init({mobile:true});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var plugin = $('.element').plugin();
    var instance = $('.element').data('plugin');
    console.log(instance);
    console.log(instance.someMethod("hello world"));
```

result,

```
Object { element={...}, options={...}, constructor=function(), more...}

hello world
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to be actually creating an instance of myPlugin, instead you're trying to access the methods statically which may or may not be what you're after.

I find it better to create an instance of my Plugin object for each time the plugin is used. An example:

```
!function(root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else {
        factory(root.jQuery);
    }
}(this, function($) {
    'use strict';

    var defaults = {

    };

    var Plugin = function(element, options) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options   = options;
    };

    Plugin.prototype = {
        constructor: Plugin,

        someMethod: function() {

        }
    }

    // Create the jQuery plugin
    $.fn.plugin = function(options) {
        options = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.data('plugin', new Plugin($this, options));
        });
    };

    // Expose defaults and Constructor
    $.fn.plugin.defaults = defaults;
    $.fn.plugin.Plugin   = Plugin;
});
```

From here - https://gist.github.com/simonsmith/4353587

Now you could use the plugin like this:

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery.plugin'], function($) {
    $('.test li').plugin({
        test: 'option1',
        test2: 'option2'
    });
});
```

An instance of the object is saved in a data property, so it can always be accessed. [Herotabs](https://github.com/simonsmith/jquery.herotabs) uses this technique:

```
var instance = $('.tabs').herotabs().data('herotabs');
instance.nextTab();
```

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't know how to use it. Please see my edit above. Thank you.

Comment: You are still trying to use it statically, rather than creating the plugin first. Is this intentional? See the part of my answer where I showed you how to access the .nextTab() method as an example. If you *really* want to use it statically then `$.fn.plugin.Plugin.prototype.someMethod()` will work

Comment: No, it is not. I am just confused with the Standard way and RequireJS's. I also tested it by creating the plugin's instance first, but I still get the error message. Please see my edit again. Thank you.

Comment: Ah okay, so for this `var instance = $('.element').data('plugin');` to work you'd need to have called the plugin first, i.e `$('.element').plugin()` Once you do that it saves an instance in the data property, as seen on line 44 - http://goo.gl/eFoWH8

Comment: Thank you. But sorry I'm still lost. Could you please see my edit 2 above again? Thanks!

Comment: So you're using `.data()` as a setter there, by passing a second argument. By writing `var instance = $('.element').data('plugin');` instead, that will *get* the instance. Then you can use it. Check http://api.jquery.com/data/ for more